# How to match ata4.00 to the apropriate /dev/sdX or actual physical disk?

Tags: disk, disk-management

Getting stuff like this in the logs:

```
Oct  2 22:11:21 jupiter kernel: [439646.093111] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6
Oct  2 22:11:21 jupiter kernel: [439646.093144] ata4.00: BMDMA stat 0x6
Oct  2 22:11:21 jupiter kernel: [439646.093176] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
Oct  2 22:11:21 jupiter kernel: [439646.093206] ata4.00: cmd 35/00:98:00:0d:ff/00:02:42:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 339968 out
Oct  2 22:11:21 jupiter kernel: [439646.093282] ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Oct  2 22:11:21 jupiter kernel: [439646.093306] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
Oct  2 22:11:21 jupiter kernel: [439646.093353] ata4: soft resetting link
Oct  2 22:11:21 jupiter kernel: [439646.265242] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
Oct  2 22:11:21 jupiter kernel: [439646.265268] ata4: EH complete
```

Now I wonder which disk to replace. But I can't find any clear mapping between "ataX.YZ" and /dev/disk/ entries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You should get more information from dmesg:

  ```
  dmesg | grep ata
  ```

  Something like:

  ```
  [    2.345126] ata2.00: ATA-8: WDC WD20EARX-00PASB0, 51.0AB51, max UDMA/133
  ```

  That would be my Wester Digital hard drive.

---

- Here's a way if you have multiple drives of one model (when above won't help):

  1. Find a mapping from SCSI host to the ata* ID:

     ```
     $ egrep "^[0-9]{1,}" /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/unique_id
     /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/unique_id:1
     /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/unique_id:2
     /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/unique_id:3
     /sys/class/scsi_host/host3/unique_id:4
     ```
  2. Find a mapping from the SCSI host to the sd* ID:

     ```
     $ ls -l /sys/block/sd*
     ... /sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
     ... /sys/block/sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb
     ```

  Now you can link those two results via the host* identifier. So if in that case I'm getting problems with ata2, I'd look for the unique_id 2 → host1, and then which sd* is host1 → sdb.

---

- I also tried to come up with a one-liner. No idea if that's robust. You first have to set the ata* as a variable:

  ```
  FAIL=ata1
  ```

  then run:

  ```
  echo "$FAIL -> $(ls -l /sys/block/ | grep $(grep "^$(echo $FAIL | cut -c 4-)" /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/unique_id | sed "s/.*\(host[0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/") | awk '{print $8}')"
  ```

  which should return something like:

  ```
  ata1 -> sda
  ```

Comment: Based on your post, I created a script https://github.com/hydrogen18/ata2dev

Answer (score 5):

In some of my servers I've two or more devices on one scsi_host. I don't know if it is correct but I assumed that it can be distingushed by target and it works for me:

```
ls -l /sys/block/sd*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-08 08:15 /sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-08 08:15 /sys/block/sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-08 08:15 /sys/block/sdc -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-08 08:15 /sys/block/sdd -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/block/sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-08 08:15 /sys/block/sde -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host9/target9:0:0/9:0:0:0/block/sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-08 08:15 /sys/block/sdf -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host10/target10:0:0/10:0:0:0/block/sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-08 08:15 /sys/block/sdg -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host11/target11:0:0/11:0:0:0/block/sdg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-08 08:15 /sys/block/sdh -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:04:00.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sdh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 2012-02-08 08:15 /sys/block/sdi -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:04:00.0/host13/target13:0:1/13:0:1:0/block/sdi
```

Simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#inspired by http://askubuntu.com/questions/64351/how-to-match-ata4-00-to-the-apropriate-dev-sdx-or-actual-physical-disk

for d in /sys/block/sd*
do
  s=`basename $d`
  h=`ls -l $d | egrep -o "host[0-9]+"`
  t=`ls -l $d | egrep -o "target[0-9:]*"`
  a2=`echo $t | egrep -o "[0-9]:[0-9]$" | sed 's/://'`
  a=`cat /sys/class/scsi_host/$h/unique_id`
  echo "$s -> ata$a.$a2"
done
```

and it's output:

```
sda -> ata4.00
sdb -> ata7.00
sdc -> ata8.00
sdd -> ata9.00
sde -> ata10.00
sdf -> ata11.00
sdg -> ata12.00
sdh -> ata14.00
sdi -> ata14.01
```

Answer (score 1):

Far too late now, but for the sake of other readers...  I had to respond to your other question "Now I wonder which disk to replace."

The ICRC error flag is almost always associated with a bad SATA cable, this is easy to replace/test.  It is slightly possible to raise the ICRC flag if power to the drive is faulty.

What is certain though, is that there is **NO** evidence of anything wrong with the drive!  Replace its SATA cable.